# How do I get TouchableOpacity to call functions in a specifid order?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I am trying to set the state of a component prior to making the API call. The problem is the API call being called first. Here is what I have.

```js
onPress={() => {
  setMeal('dinner');
  addToLogButtonPressed();
}}
```

When I press the button `addToLogButtonPressed();` calls first which causes an error.

How to I call `setMeal` before `addToLogButtonPressed`?

Comment: Dose addToLogButtonPressed() function uses setMeal("dinner") value ?

Comment: Yes it does use setMeal("dinner") value

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use useEffect to do that

```
const [meal, setMeal] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  addToLogButtonPressed();
}, [meal])

onPress={() => {
  setMeal('dinner');
}}
```

Comment: That didnt do it

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem for my previous project simply just pass meal value to your addToLogButtonPressed() and access it inside the function.
If you are not using "dinner" value anywhere else you can skip setting state it will save you one Re-render.

```
onPress={() => {
 setMeal('dinner');
 addToLogButtonPressed('dinner'); // like this
}}
```